# what's the purpose of keys in this schema of windowing?

Tags: streaming, apache-beam, windowing

[image]

To what refer keys? is there an example of use in the case of sliding window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys basically allow you group data in your input stream logically together.

This can allow processing optimisations, as the grouped (by key) data within a window can be processed independently in parallel with other groups in the stream.

As a good example, from the Apache Link documentation (https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html), a stream might contain traffic sensors readings and you might want 30 second windows - i.e. a count for the traffic passing the sensor every 30 seconds.

If you have multiple sensors you can have the data keyed by the sensor id and calculate the traffic passing each individual sensor every 30 seconds, as well as the total.